# Outputing Array Formula in one row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, google-sheets-filter

I came across the below array formula, which works really well, I'm just struggling to tweak it, and barely understand it's inner workings, but it's very good. Instead of displaying a total of stock left per line, I wondered if someone could help me keep it on one line? Example on Google link below.

Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"";IF(B4:B&C4:C="",,MMULT((VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),FILTER({ROW(A4:A),A4:A},A4:A<>""),2,1)=TRANSPOSE(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),FILTER({ROW(A4:A),A4:A},A4:A<>""),2,1)))*(ROW(A4:A)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A4:A))),B4:B-C4:C))})
```

Google link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YqG3KwGzIJCiYwSBicfct8MSKSppUtE8RTB-6iY1C8Q/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B4:B<>"", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4:A, 
 QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A4:C, 
 "select A,sum(B),sum(C) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A 
  label sum(B)'',sum(C)''", 0), 
 "select Col1,Col2-Col3 
  label Col2-Col3''", 0), 
 "where Col2 > 0", 0), 2, 0)), ))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi User0, thanks for the help, but this isn't what I'm looking for. Do you think I need to change the IF statement around?

Comment: I have managed to do it with a singular formula on the google link in column F, and now struggling to get it in an array...

Comment: no, literally just nothing, or rather " " in formula terms.

Comment: @Ceebee86 answer updated

Comment: Thanks, that's great. :) I modified it a little for my needs, but it does exactly what I was aiming for. :)